# Objects pushed to empty array aren't accessible in the script

Tags: javascript

Don't know whether I am doing something wrong here, but I am trying to access items in an array elsewhere inside my script.

Here's where I would pass in the object (in the DOM):

```
App.config({
    dependencies: {
        'html5shiv' : 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js',
        'respondjs' : 'http://respondjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/respond.js'
    }
});
```

Then create an empty array, and push each item in the dependencies object into it. I then want to loop through this *deps* array further down in my script, but it actually prints *[ ]* empty on the console, unless I put the log straight after the *for in* loop. Can anyone advise how I can access these items in the array elsewhere?

```
var deps = [];

App.config = function (obj) {
    for (var key in obj.dependencies) {
        deps.push(key);
    }
};

console.log(deps);
```

Ideally I want to do, here's a http://jsfiddle.net/WJh4E/:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < deps.length; i++) {
    console.log(deps[i]);
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect the line defining App.config needs to be above the line where it is actually used. Anonymous functions do not get hoisted like named functions do.

Comment: Also, you are only saving the keys from obj.  You are not saving the values.  That's not quite sane.

Comment: declare first, call later

Comment: Please post the code as you have it, don't break it into parts...

Comment: I updated the code a few minutes ago with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WJh4E

Comment: Also, you can emit an object with console.log, you don't need to break it up.  Chrome even has a nice clickable viewer for it.

Comment: @Halcyon21 I'm sorry, I didn't notice the link... anyway, your'e logging before executing the function. `App.config = function () {..}` doesn't execute the function, it just defines a property to `App`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to declare and instantiate the `App`.

See here the code below :

```
var deps = [];
var App= new Object();
App.config = function (obj) {
    for (var key in obj.dependencies) {
        deps.push(key);
    }
};

App.config({
    dependencies: {
        'html5shiv' : 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js',
        'respondjs' : 'http://respondjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/respond.js'
    }
});



console.log("deps::"+deps);

for (var i = 0; i < deps.length; i++) {
    console.log("deps[i]::"+deps[i]);
 }
```

See the working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/9xUk4/

Comment: You've met his initial requirement.  But his requirement seems broken.  His App.config throws away the URLs.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  He should be saving the arg within App's object. perhaps with  `this.conf = obj`

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually call the function.  Add this to before the console.log:

```
App.config();
```

All you did there was declare the function and assign it to a variable.

Comment: I thought I was doing that already in the DOM? Or would that not work somehow? :)

Comment: No idea what you mean by DOM in this context.  In the example code you gave you are not doing it.  Is this code correct?  If you see an empty result in the log it is most likely one of two things -- deps is out of scope where you are logging it or you did not run your function.

Comment: So by in the DOM, I mean, I'm calling it like a plugin and passing an object into it, inside Script tags. Here's my setup: http://jsfiddle.net/WJh4E/

Comment: @Halcyon21: you just put the console logging in the wrong place. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/WJh4E/1/